# "who" on CentOS does not show WinSCP clients

Tags: ip, centos7, winscp

I use CentOS 7 with Apache server. The problem `who` command does not show clients connected with WinSCP. Can't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem who command does not show clients connected with WinSCP. Can't understand why.

Apparently, then, you are operating from a false premise.  The `who` command does not promise to name everyone interacting with the system in any way whatever.  Roughly speaking, `who` tells you about users who have an associated *terminal*, whether physical or virtual.  Connecting via an scp client does not establish a login session or allocate a terminal for [`who`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/who) to report on.

Contrast users who connect via `ssh` clients: these do get a terminal assigned to them, and they do show up in the output of a suitably-timed `who` command.